# MariaDB, do new inserts replace deleted rows on disk?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Can someone point me in the right direction, i can't find any documentation on this behavior.

We know when you delete rows from a table you end up with "holes" which you can defrag with `OPTIMIZE`. Do new inserts automatically fill in those holes if left alone? Is there a way to force that behavior if not? Using InnoDB tables for revolving logs, deleting old rows and adding new, would the table roll over or continuously consume disk space? Or would a different engine be better suited for this?

Yes i know of table partitions, i want to explore all options first.

Comment: If the rows are variable length, it depends on whether the new row will fit in any holes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is mostly a non-issue, I will assume you are asking for academic reasons?

InnoDB (you should be using that Engine!) stores the data (and each secondary index) in separate B+Trees.

The data's BTree is ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  The various leaf nodes will be filled to different degrees, based on the order of inserts, deletes, updates (that change the row length), temporary transactional locks on rows, etc, etc.

That last one is because one transaction sees effectively an instantaneous snapshot of the data, possibly different than another transaction's view.  This implies that multiple copies of a row may coexist.

The buffer_pool holds 16KB blocks.  Each block holds a variable number of rows.  This number changes with the changing tides.  If too adjacent blocks become "too empty", they will be combined.

Totally empty blocks (say, due to lots of deletes) will be put on a free chain for later reuse by Inserts.  But note that the disk used by the table will not shrink.

The failure to shrink is usually not a problem -- most tables grow; any shrinkage is soon followed by a new growth spurt.

`PARTITIONs` are usually not worth using.  However, that is the best way to "keep data for only 90 days", then use `DROP PARTITION` instead of a big, slow `DELETE`.  (That is about the *only* use for `PARTITION`.)

If you add up all the bytes in the INTs (4 bytes each) VARCHARs (pick the average length), etc, etc, you will get what seems like a good estimate for the disk space being used.  But due to the things discussed above, you need to multiply that number by 2 to 3 to a better estimate of the disk space actually consumed by the table.

Comment: Not that i expect the disk space to shrink, just that it will equalize at a certain size as the deletes allow new rows to take their place. So long as it doesn't keep growing and one day consuming the entire drive. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @Private_Citizen - Correct.  For typical activity, the 2x-3x that I mentioned holds even after years of activity.  (An atypical situation is right after deleting most of the rows.)

Comment: @Private_Citizen - The partition technique may be useful for our use case (logs).  More: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint